# setImageBitmap don't work in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I'm trying to create a button like the ImageButton. And faced with a vexing problem. After applying setImageBitmap, with ImageView nothing happens. Bitmap itself contains image(not null). Moreover, the same function(*ImageManager.getImage("menu", id)*), I use elsewhere in the program, which have to contain the Bitmap in ListView Adapter, works fine.

```
for( int i = 0; i < MenuArray.size(); i++)
        {
            View buttonView = MainActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.top_button, MenuLayout, false);
            buttons[i] = (ImageView) buttonView.findViewById(R.id.imageForeground);
            ImageView imageBackground = (ImageView) buttonView.findViewById(R.id.imageBackground);
            imageBackground.setImageBitmap(ImageManager.getImage("menu", MenuArray.get(i).id));

            MenuLayout.addView(buttonView);
        }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/cart_item" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageForeground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/button_selector" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: "nothing happens" meaning the `ImageView` still displays the `src` image it originally had from the XML definition or it displays nothing?

Comment: @Devunwired Nothing displays. Completely transparent ImageView

Comment: That means `setImageBitmap()` did something because it cleared out the default image source.  Your certain you verified that the result from your `getImage()` method at that point is not null?  If you DON'T call `setImageBitmap()` does the default image display?  If not, it may be a layout problem during inflation.

Comment: If I DON'T call setImageBitmap(), the picture is displayed by default. I also tried to set the image through setImageDrawable(), pointing to an image from the drawable and everything worked.

Comment: That definitely sounds like the `Bitmap` being returned from the `ImageManager` at that time is either null or empty, even if at some time later it properly returns an image.

Comment: It's true. Strange that it was not null